# How to draw a line with ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses

I know the basics of C++ ncurses, but I do not know how to draw a simple line between two coordinates.

example:

2----------3

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: What kind of line drawing do you want? `ncurses` only prints characters. To do arbitrary graphics I think you would have to do some wizardry like pick the right character set and write your own drawing primitives. Not trivial tbh. Not so hard  for simple window frames perhaps.

Comment: I want a line, which consists of the character - like in my example. A line should look like this ------------

Comment: Uh, how about a loop?

Comment: How can I put it in a loop? I want to draw it with  mvprintw(x, y, "-")

Answer (score 4):

```
   int hline(chtype ch, int n);
   int whline(WINDOW *win, chtype ch, int n);
```

> The  `hline`  and `whline` functions draw a horizontal (left to right) line using `ch` starting at the current cursor position in  the  window.   The current  cursor position is not changed.  The line is at most `n` characters long, or as many as fit into the window.

As for the character, you probably want `ACS_HLINE`, but `-` would probably work too... perhaps better.

Comment: thanks! is there a function to draw a vertical line(up to down) as well ? i need this too